# Can't import pprint

Tags: python, import, pprint

Programming newbie here. Whenever I attempt to 'import pprint' in the Python IDLE, I get the following error:

```
>>> import pprint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    import pprint
  File "C:\Python34\pprint.py", line 10, in <module>
    pprint(count)
NameError: name 'pprint' is not defined
```

Thought I would try to 'pip install pprint' in command line but that didn't work either:

```
PS C:\Python34> pip install pprint
Collecting pprint
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pprint (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pprint
```

I thought Python 3.4.3 was supposed to come with pprint module. How do I get it to work? Can't seem to import pprint but all other modules are working fine. I need the pprint module to work for completion of some exercises from Automate The Boring Stuff with Python. Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've named a program `pprint`. Rename your program to something other than `pprint.py` and remove any `pprint.pyc` file that might be present.

Comment: Yep you can tell from the traceback (importing `pprint` tries to *call* `pprint(count)` which it obviously should not)

Comment: why doesn't python suggest us to rename the script to something else?